# table is not updated in Angular5/6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am new in angular5/6. Have used *ngFor with static data which works fine but table to not updating when fetching data from servers 
This HTML table is not getting update

```
{{userList | json}}--this shows []
<div class="container color-light">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let y of userList">
    <td>{{y.id}}</td>
    <td>{{y.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but data is received in component

```
userList:JsonListInterface[]=[];
  ngOnInit() {
this.callingDataFromHttp();}

callingDataFromHttp(){
 this.listS.getData().subscribe(function(response){
   this.userList = response;
   console.log(this.userList);//this shows proper array with id and name
 });}
```

can anyone tell where i am going wrong, as frontend table is empty even after getting data.

Comment: whats the error in console?

Comment: Now explain to me, how should I know from that code what `this.listS.getData()` is doing or what should it do ?

Comment: can you share the result shown in the console ?

Comment: 100% sure that there is no issue with provided code and there is something around that breaks application.

Comment: Don't use annymous functions. Use arrow functions. `subscribe(response => this.userList = response)`

Comment: @Antoniossss: That's not relevant as long as he is getting the data in subscription

Comment: @AshishRanjan And how do you know that? Cuz I don't

Comment: this is console Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]

Comment: there is no error ..code is working fine...

Comment: @Antoniossss: beacause he has mentioned in the comment in code.. `console.log(this.userList);//this shows proper array with id and name`

Comment: Code is **not** working fine. Read my comment, and read the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: component  in console in giving array but not in html

Comment: @AshishRanjan I can write to you that given code works fine for me - that iwll be the same "fact" as provided. Unless given hard output such statements have no value to me.

Comment: As you can see, OP is loosing `this` context and claims it works fine. Too bad for him. Duplicate

Comment: Use arrow function or `bind` that anonymous function.

Comment: it is working with `response =>
            this.userList = response`
thanks @JBNizet

Comment: @Antoniossss: I agree that it was just a fact without a proof, but somehow I didn't like the way you asked the OP for the content inside `this.listS.getData()`. Hence I commented. And as far as loosing `this` is concerned, he will not get to know the difference in a console log, `this.userList = response;` will get assigned to the `window` and log will be what he desires... but from the `window`

Answer (score 0):

**TS**

```
    userList: object;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.callingDataFromHttp();
    }

    callingDataFromHttp(){
        this.listS.getData().subscribe(response =>{
            this.userList = response;
         });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container color-light">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: code and binding is working good with `response => this.userList = response`
no need to change to `object`